# Google Site へ Google Drive上のファイルをダウンロードするリンクの埋め込み

Tags: html, google-spreadsheet, url, google-sites

Google siteでのHTMLの埋め込みで、ワンクリックでドライブ上に共有されているファイルのダウンロードができるようにしていました。
`<a href="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=ファイルのID">ダウンロード</a>`
ですが、久しぶりに試してみるとダウンロードできなくなっていました。
ファイルの共有設定は「このリンクを知っている 組織 の全員が編集できます」になっています。
リンクを開くと無題の空白のページが表示されるだけでダウンロードされません。
念のため、ファイルのIDが変更されていないか確認しましたが、以前と同じでした。

また、スプレッドシートに埋め込んでいた上記と同様のダウンロードリンク も機能しなくなっていました。

このURLはもう機能しないのでしょうか？

Comment: 解決策ではなく申し訳ありません。もしもブラウザとしてChromeを使用されているようですと、こちらの問題と関連している可能性があります。https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/157368720 今のところはまだ改善されていないようです。今の段階での回避策はブラウザを変えてみるとのことです。

Comment: Chromeのアップデートに伴うバグなんですね？
修正されるのを待つしかなさそうですね。
ありがとうございました。